# Crystal Reports Issue with Image not displaying when i re-open the report

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am Using Crystal Reports 2008.  When I load a .JPEG, .PNG or .TIF, I see the image in my report, yet when I save the report and close Crystal Reports then re-open the report the image no longer appears.  There is the location where the image should be and when I click where the image should be I only see the outline where the image should be. The image does take up a whole page. I have data that sits on top of the image. The image when created it put in the back.  I tried leaving it in the front but get the same results when I close and re-open.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the size of the image. Try reducing the pixels and it will work. This occurred with me too but i resolved it by reducing size of image. Crystal is not going to show you this error but there is some limitation on the image size

Comment: Adding a source or documentation is appreciated

Comment: This is my own experience because i was stuck with this issue too. I cannot find any source regarding this. If you are stuck with this issue it might help if you reduce the pixel size

Answer (score 0):

Try copy/paste the image rather than Insert Image. It usually works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the image colors helped in my case. I saved the image as 256-colors PNG instead of JPEG and worked fine.